# Setting child value on javascript proxy never actually gets updated

Tags: javascript

So this is an example I created to create an observable object.

Question is - why isn't the variable 'update' actually updated?
Also if there is a reason I should not implement it like this? and a better strategy please advise?

```js
window.dataSubscriber = new Proxy({
  history: [],
  update: ''
}, {
  set: function (target, key, value) {
    window.dataSubscriber.history.push(value);
    return value;
  }
});

window.dataSubscriber.update = 'John';
window.dataSubscriber.update = 'Smith';

console.log(window.dataSubscriber) 

/*
output:
{
  history: ['John', 'Smith'],
  update: ''
}
*/
```

**Other attempts that failed for me**

- I tried doing window.dataSubscriber = new Proxy([], ...) and when pushing to that, it never keeps the history, and overwrites the original array value
- I tried doing window.dataSubscriber.history.push() outside the set method, and that never triggers the set method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override the set method, then it's your responsibility to do the actual update.

So you just need `target[key] = value;`

eg.

```js
window.dataSubscriber = new Proxy({
  history: [],
  update: ''
}, {
  set: function (target, key, value) {
    window.dataSubscriber.history.push(value);
    target[key] = value;
    return value;
  }
});

window.dataSubscriber.update = 'John';
window.dataSubscriber.update = 'Smith';

console.log(window.dataSubscriber) 

/*
output:
{
  history: ['John', 'Smith'],
  update: ''
}
*/
```

Comment: omg. I've been trying to figure this out for ages. Thankyou. That opens up a lot of doors now.